# Mysql - Pdo: getting the id for data selection - from another php file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a couple of nearly identical  files in a large number of folders.

The **difference is the id** set in every folder/file.

I would love to **put 1 file in each folder** with the corresponding id of that folder/customer.
All files in that folder would include/import/ that number/file
 AND
all datas would be changed with little effort...

Is that possible?

lets say i put a .php file in each folder with just the id number of that customer. 
All file would somehow import that number or file...

**AT the moment i use that in every file:**

```
<?php require_once('../connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table_A where id = 1";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_Recordset1)
?>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: create a function, that accepts the ID as parameter and returns that data

Comment: So you currently have a folder for every different customer???

Comment: yes! there are more then 200 folders, containing 10 php files.
lots of photos and other files..

Comment: `create a function, that accepts the ID as parameter and returns that data '

well, I guess I will have to some how 
**get the id by an external file**
AND would have to pass content of that file to the where statement...
I guess!
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table_A where id = 1";

a function within every file would not do that --- am I wrong?

Comment: Any variable set in an included file(php file) will "bleed out" into the script they are required or included into. Is the only difference in these folders the customer?(same thing shown but for a different customer?)

Comment: I would have a customer table containing a customers information, and get their id from something like that.

Comment: The _main file is a template_ for an apartment directory. All data will be drawn out of database. By setting a different id, the page would load another appartement, other pictures, other email adress for inquiry form and on and on... 
so ... the id is the only data that I would have to change in order to show another customer.
With a number of customers and corresponding files, the change of id's is quite a work!
**So, the idea is to put 1 single file in a folder.. and all other files in there would "import" the information/id from that file...**

Comment: the file with the corresponding ID could be a .php or .txt  or .csv ... file.
The challenge for me is how to write the mysql syntax:
"SELECT * FROM database where id xxxxx"  -->>>xxxx there's the question :-)

Comment: So are you asking how to write a prepared statement? Or how to concatenate your id onto your query string? I feel like I'm still missing something ....

Comment: its about the prepared statement - on **how to get data from another file into a where clausel** The where clausel is the id. Normaly id=10 or so.
In my case an external file, where the id is stored. like in a text file.

Comment: This page has some prepared statements examples: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php , as for the id itself, you can put it in a .php file like anything else and import it, though you might put it in a file that is already included everywhere, or include it into that file, so you only have to do it once.